# How to sort a PHP array?

Tags: php, mysql

Is there any way to "custom" sort an array?  For instance, if I have the following numbers:

```
$array = array('0' => 1, '1' => 2, '2' => 3);
```

I would like it to order them in this fashion:

```
$array = array('0' => 2, '1' => 1, '2' => 3);
```

How would I do this or is it not possible?  I am basically wanting to list this array in one database field for each user, but each order will be different depending on how the user sorts the array.

Thanks, Jake

Comment: What's the ordering logic? What determines whether a value is pushed forward or backward?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use

- [`usort`](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) — *Sort an array **by values** using a user-defined comparison function* or
- [`uksort`](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.uksort.php) — *Sort an array **by keys** using a user-defined comparison function* or
- [`uasort`](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php) — *Sort an array with a user-defined comparison function and **maintain index association***

Each of these accepts an array and a [user-defined comparison function aka callback](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/language.pseudo-types.php#language.types.callback). What you put into the comparion function is up to you. As of PHP5.3 you can also use [SplHeaps to create ordered collections](http://github.com/salathe/spl-examples/wiki/SplMaxHeap).

Answer (score 0):

you may also want to have a look at array_multisort()

Answer (score 0):

It might be better to let the database sort the array upon retrieval with the users settings. I think that is almost always preferable over sorting in PHP.

edit: 
I forgot that the array is probably stored as a single object so the database just handles it as an object and not an array. To still enable serverside (database server) sorting, arrays could also be expressed as seperate tables:

userID : index0
userID : index1
etc...

but this might give too much data overhead.